# ¿How to handle OnRowClick event of ASPxGridView Devexpress server-side?

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview, onrowclick

This is my gridview code. So the events OnFocusedRowChanged and OnSelectionChanged doesn't work and i don't know how can i do this work, i need your help people

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBXAo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Refer these:**
[ASPxGridView - The server-side SelectionChanged is not fired](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t580763/aspxgridview-the-server-side-selectionchanged-is-not-fired)
[ASPxGridView - How to process the SelectionChanged event on the server side](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t288861/aspxgridview-how-to-process-the-selectionchanged-event-on-the-server-side)

> By default, the ASPxGridView processes change of selection only on the
> client-side. If you wish the server-side
> [ASPxGridView.SelectionChanged](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_SelectionChangedtopic) to be fired, set the
> [ASPxGridView.SettingsBehavior.ProcessSelectionChangedOnServer](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridBehaviorSettings_ProcessSelectionChangedOnServertopic)
> property to true or handle the client-side
> [ASPxClientGridView.SelectionChanged](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientGridView_SelectionChangedtopic) event and set the
> [processOnServer](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientProcessingModeEventArgs_processOnServertopic) property to True in this event handler.

Comment: Perfect! this worked for me friend, thank u so much