# The server-side ASPxGridView FocusedRowChanged event is not fired inside UpdatePanel

Tags: gridview, devexpress

This is my code gridview, I have already set SettingsBehavior-ProcessFocusedRowChangedOnServer in true and false but doesn't work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UxJh.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [¿How to handle OnRowClick event of ASPxGridView Devexpress server-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64779187/how-to-handle-onrowclick-event-of-aspxgridview-devexpress-server-side)

Comment: Bro, i need it with event FocusedRowChanged, with SelectionChanged no

Comment: Why did you ask the duplicate question then? Did the previous answer was useful? Why didn't you contact the DevExpress Support directly?

Comment: the questions are differents, look